# Pattern for handling HTTP requests via channels

Tags: go

I am writing a web application where I have a long running goroutine.
I want to delegate all HTTP requests to this goroutine via channels.
The pattern that I have come across is:

```
// Internal long running goroutine
for{
  select{
  case e := <-event: //web request
    req := e.req
    // do something
    ....
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
       //log  
    default: 
      e.replyTo <- result
    }
  }
}

// Web handler
http.HandleFunc("/bar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  //decode request etc
  ...

  replyTo := make(chan interface{}, 1)
  ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.BackGround())
  event <- Event{req: req, ctx: ctx, replyTo: replyTo}
  select{
  case <-time.After(time.Second):
     cancel()
     //return 500
  case r := <-replyTo:
    // return some response
  }
})
```

I do see that there is one single go-routine at the end, so parallelism is lost but I am okay with it.

Is this pattern the right way of doing this?
What other approaches can be suggested?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why not just use `net/http`?

Comment: I am using net/http... the handler function is delegating the work to goroutine which has data

Comment: "Is this pattern the right way of doing this?" -- the right way of doing what? You still haven't explained your goal. Why go to all this effort to seemingly undermine the standard library, and make your code less efficient?

Comment: The handler function doesnt have enough state to handle request..It delegates it to another goroutine which has the required data procured from some other place.
is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Shank Yes exactly

Comment: There's no reason to use a goroutine, if the goal is context propagation.

Comment: This question looks pretty obviously like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Until the actual _goal_ is stated, I don't think any proper answer will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this pattern the right way of doing this?

Assuming you are trying to manage where state in a single go routine, I would say **no**. I think it would be better to have some form of a state manager that is responsible for thread safety. Therefore the handler should take in something that can manage the state and simply expose a few methods to the handler.

```
type State interface{
  Load() (string, error)
  Save(something string) error
}
```

Decoupling the code will pay off for you later on. It will also allow unit tests for both the handler and the State that can be focused and readable.

Comment: Doesn't the channel guarantee thread safety? The channel is being read by 1 single goroutine and hence at any point of time, it would service a single request.

Comment: Yes it can. However my point is that the pattern of having the handler take on thread safety is not great decoupling of concerns. If later you decide the channels are non-performant, you would want the ability to refactor without having to rewrite every single part.